# Excel issue with automatic created worksheets

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

HI I have created a VBA that takes info from a ALL data sheet and plots it in worksheets.
The worksheets get automatically generated which is great but the issue is that VBA is only supposed to create Unique worksheets - however this is not the case.
Example: if in my ALL data sheet I have IKEA 3 times then the first time the vba encounters IKEA then it should create a worksheet while it should ignore any repeats.

**Actual**

> IKEA; Sheet 2 ; Sheet 3

**Wanted**

> IKEA

**VBA Code**

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
   Dim iReply As Integer
   Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

   On Error Resume Next

   Range("B1").End(xlUp).AdvancedFilter _
       Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rListPaste.Cells(1, 1), Unique:=True

   Set MyRange = Sheets("ALL").Range("B1")
   Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

   For Each MyCell In MyRange
       Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
       Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
   Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code (it creates new sheet only if there is no sheets with name `MyCell.Value`):

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()

  Dim iReply As Integer
  Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range
  Dim sh as Worksheet

  On Error Resume Next

  Range("B1").End(xlUp).AdvancedFilter _
      Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rListPaste.Cells(1, 1), Unique:=True

  Set MyRange = Sheets("ALL").Range("B1")
  Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

  For Each MyCell In MyRange
      Set sh = Nothing
      Set sh=Sheets(MyCell.Value)
      If sh is Nothing Then
          Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet  
          Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
      End If        
  Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Simoco,
the issue is that I have other values in between IKEA's which can also be repetitive so the ALL data looks more like
IKEA,
MARKS,
toyota,
saINSBURY,
ikea,
sAINSBURY,
and so on
Your code worked for the first unique values but then when it met a repetition then it stopped :) ...

Comment: I believe my code should cope with your problem. Before creating a new sheet I do check if there is a list with the same name. If not, then I create a new list.

Comment: I thank you for the help, however I have tried 3 times now, and the issue continues.
It seems that it does not resume after it meets the first duplicate?

Comment: Try to delete `On Error Resume Next` statement and what error will you get?

Comment: run time error 424 
Object required
and then the debugger points at 

Range("B1").End(xlUp).AdvancedFilter _
      Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=rListPaste.Cells(1, 1), Unique:=True

Comment: it is because you use undeclared variable `rListPaste`

Comment: Yes, that is just brilliant and works as intended. Thank you!